# How to set first 6 rows and all columns to 0 in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 2-d matrix that I would like to change the first 6 rows and last 6 rows and their corresponding columns to 0.

I have this right now but it is only doing it by a single row.

```
at_1(4, :) = zeros(1, 141); % set first 6 rows to zero val
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should make the trick

```
at_1(1:6, :) = 0;
at_1(end-5:end, :) = 0;
```

You are basically saying to use the values from `1 to 6` in all columns by using `(1:6, :)` and the second statement is the same but using the `end` instead.

Comment: is there any performance reduction by using `zeros` instead of `0`?

Comment: It's a function call, those always have overhead.